# how to fix this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im programming discord bot in discord.js but somehow it doesn't want to respond to commands, I enter any command, it always shuts down and writes error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined", I've already searched the stack overflow, but I didn't find anything, or found nothing it's my case. If you know how to solve this, I will be happy to answer. Thank you
This is my index.js:

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const {TOKEN} = require('./config.json');
const prefix = '!';
const fs = require('fs');
 
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
 
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    language = 0;
    console.log('Im online!');                                  // ↓ WATCHING PLAYING STREAMING COMPETETIVE
    client.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: 'Your mom', type: "WATCHING" } });
});
 
client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
 
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
 
    if(command === 'ping'){
    if(language == 1) {
        client.commands.get('ping-en').execute(message, args);}
    if(language == 0) {
        client.commands.get('ping-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'help'){
      if(language == 1) {
          client.commands.get('help-en').execute(message, args);}
      if(language == 0) {
        client.commands.get('help-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'clear'){
      if(language == 1) {
        client.commands.get('clear-en').execute(message, args);}
      if(language == 0)
        client.commands.get('clear-cz').execute(message, args);
    } else if(command === 'kick'){
      if(language == 1){
        client.commands.get('kick-en').execute(message, args);}
      if(language == 0){
        client.commands.get('kick-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'ban'){
      if(language == 1){
        client.commands.get('ban-en').execute(message, args);}
      if(language == 0){
        client.commands.get('ban-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'poll'){
      if(language == 1){
        client.commands.get('poll-en').execute(message, args);}
      if(language == 0){
        client.commands.get('poll-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'broadcast'){
        if(language == 1){
            client.commands.get('broadcast-en').execute(message, args);}
        if(language == 0){
            client.commands.get('broadcast-cz').execute(message, args);}
    } else if(command === 'czech'){
        message.reply('Jazyk byl přepnut na český!')
        language = 0;
        console.log(language);
    } else if(command === 'english'){
        message.reply('Language has been set to english!')
        language = 1;
        console.log(language);
    }

});
    client.login(TOKEN);
```

and this is my help.js:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
module.exports.execute = {
    name: 'help',
    description: "Help!",
    execute(message, args){
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('        ↓ Commands ↓')
        .setDescription('\n\n***- Default:***\n`!ping`\n\n***- Moderation:***\n`!clear <number max is 100!>`\n`!kick <member ping>`\n`!ban <member ping>`\n`!poll <ping channel> <message>`\n`!broadcast <ping channel> <message>`')
        .setFooter('By ItsMeDarkness#9538 and L0wiee#9552')
        .setColor('RED')
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
}
```

Bot turns on normally, but when I enter any command, it turns off and displays this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined
"
Thank you for the responce

Comment: Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined means that somewhere in your code, there's `xyz.execute` and `xyz` is undefined. Test the ping command by adding `console.log(client.commands.get('ping-en'))` before calling `.execute()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
 
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

`command` has the form

```
{
    execute: {
        name: ...,
        description: ...,
        execute: ...
    }
}
```

That is `command.name` is `undefined`
and `command.execute.name` is `"help"`

Fix `module.exports.execute = {` to `module.exports = {` in `help-en.js` and others.

Comment: no, I don't have a help file, I have a help-en.js file and a help-cz.js file, so I don't know what I'm wrong, you don't know exactly how to fix this?

Comment: Fix `module.exports.execute = {` to `module.exports = {`.
If that doesn't help, then I don't know.

Comment: yeah, but where :D

Comment: In command files: `help-en.js`, `help-cz.js` and others.

Comment: And you can make it very easy to check the command (down to a couple of lines instead of the 'if' tower). If you are interested in how, I will tell you.